# Hashtable with double hashing and twin primes without secondary hash function

Tags: hashtable

I was told we can have a hashtable with double hashing without any secondary hash function and larger twin prime as capacity. I am wondering how how accessing an element would look like.

First try to get index using the following:

```
index = hash % capacity
```

Otherwise use the following where `attempt` starts from zero:

```
index = (hash + attempt++) % (capacity - 2)
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: I don't know if I was clear with double hashing. I meant open addressing and no secondary has function

Comment: The `% (capacity - 2)` part makes no sense - that just makes the last two entries in the table unusable.  `(hash + attempt++)` on the left side will work, but that's "linear probing" - it tends to lead to clumps of used table entries, anything that hashes into that general area will have to make a LOT of attempts to find the next free entry.  See "quadratic probing" for one better way of doing it.

Comment: The thing I was told was we can use `capacity -2` as smaller number is also prime. I am not sure how

Comment: But there's no fundamental reason why a hashtable has to have a prime size.  Some specific probing algorithms might require it, to ensure that they eventually visit every entry, but with the linear probing you're currently using, prime sizes are completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Page 614 of "Data Structures and Other Objects Using C++ (4th Edition)" describes the approach:

[image]